# Get column value associated to another column maximum in dplyr's across

Tags: r, dplyr, across

After grouping by species and taken max Sepal.Length (column 1) for each group I need to grab the value of column 2 to 4 that are associated to maximum value of column 1 (by group). I'm able to do so for each single column at once but not in an `across` process. Any tips?

```
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)
data(iris)
```

Summarize by species with data associates to max sepal.length (by group), column by column:

```
iris_summary <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(
    max_sep_length = max(Sepal.Length),
    sep_w_associated_to = Sepal.Width[which.max(Sepal.Length)],
    pet_l_associated_to = Petal.Length[which.max(Sepal.Length)],
    pet_w_associated_to = Petal.Width[which.max(Sepal.Length)]
  )
```

Now I would like obtain the same result using `across`, but the outcome is different from that I expected (the df **iris_summary** has now same number of rows as **iris**, I can't understand why...)

```
iris_summary <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(
    max_sepa_length = max(Sepal.Length),
    across(
      .cols = Sepal.Width : Petal.Width,
      .funs = ~ .x[which.max(Sepal.Length)]
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr) # devel can have `.by` or use `group_by(Species)`
iris %>% 
   slice_max(Sepal.Length, n = 1, by = 'Species')
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
2          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
3          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
```

Comment: dayyym! Nice upcoming feature

Answer (score 1):

in base R you could do:

```
merge(aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species, iris, max), iris)

     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2
2 versicolor          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4
3  virginica          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to do the same with across, here is one option:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ .[which.max(Sepal.Length)]))
```

```
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa              5.8         4            1.2         0.2
2 versicolor          7           3.2          4.7         1.4
3 virginica           7.9         3.8          6.4         2
```